# Can we use baking powder instead of activated yeast for making pizza dough?if yes than in which proportion we can use it?

Tags: baking

Can we use baking powder instead of activated yeast for making pizza dough wouldn't it effect the recipe?if yes than in which proportion we can use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly make pizza dough with baking powder. However, adapting a yeast recipe to baking powder will be very difficult. I would suggest searching for a pizza dough recipe that already uses baking powder rather than trying to adapt your recipe.